# Joining tables with count and sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables 
loanform and schedule_loanform
loanform
[image]

I need the MySQL query but could not solve it can anyone help me?

Comment: share your query and error

Comment: Can you add data to your question as text or to sql fiddle please.

Comment: I have tried many but all are not working....

Comment: you can post what u have tried and create the tables on sql fiddle.

Comment: @AliRazaMarchal What is the expect result date condition?  Is `Due_Date`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

Use two subquery two and `JOIN` by `Zone`

Your `Due_Date` format is `dd-mm-yyyy` so need to use `STR_TO_DATE` convert date.The get the date Between you condition.

```
SELECT TotalZoneCase,Region,T.Zone,LoanAmount,MarkUp
FROM 
(
    SELECT Zone,SUM(LoanAmount) AS LoanAmount,COUNT(1) as TotalZoneCase
    FROM loanform
    GROUP BY Zone
) AS T
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT l.Zone,l.Region,SUM(MarkUp)  MarkUp
    FROM loanform l 
    INNER JOIN schedule_loanform s on l.App_ID = s.App_ID
    WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(Due_Date, '%d-%m-%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2018', '%d-%m-%Y') and  STR_TO_DATE(Due_Date, '%d-%m-%Y')<=STR_TO_DATE('31-06-2018', '%d-%m-%Y')
    GROUP BY l.Zone,l.Region
) T2 ON T.Zone = T2.Zone
```

[SQLFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/izpWJ5UtoevxkRvDus79Wo/2)

Answer (score 1):

> As per your requirement, simply try this

```
SELECT COUNT(lf.Zone) AS TotalZoneCase, lf.Region, lf.Zone, SUM(lf.LoanAmount),
SUM(sl.MarkUp) FROM loanform lf
INNER JOIN schedule_loanform sl ON lf.App_ID = sl.App_ID
WHERE '2018-01-01' >= DATE(Disburse_Date) <= '2018-06-30'
GROUP BY Region, Zone ORDER BY lf.App_ID;
```